# Generating a Series of Alternating Exponential Processes Elegantly

Tags: pandas, random, exponential-distribution, numpy-random

Suppose I start with a time series:

```
time = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=600, freq='5M')
```

I'd like now to generate a corresponding series, say `'on'`, so that the entries of `'on'` will correspond to an [exponential process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) that is `True` with mean 10, then `False` with mean 20, then `True` with mean 10, and so on. (Conceptually, this fits a person who wakes for 10 minutes approximately, then sleeps for 20.)

I.e., `'on'` should be generated as the following pseudo-code:

```
while not reached 600:
    generate o0 ~ exponential(10), fill the next o0 entries of 'on' with 'True'
    generate o1 ~ exponential(20), fill the next o1 entries of 'on' with 'False'
```

This is trivial to do with loops. Is there some nicer way to do it?